# Selenium testing JAVA - I can't configure certificate auto-selection for a specific URL when opening ChromeDriver on MAC

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ssl, selenium-chromedriver, ssl-certificate

I am writing autotests using Maven+Selenium+JUnitxz.
During UI testing, I can't configure certificate auto-selection so as not to click on the window manually.

I have already tried ChromeOptions and ignoring the certificate, it is not working.
I found a suggestion for creating a file /Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist, but when running ChromeDriver, this file disappeared.
The content of the file is as follows:

```
    <plist version="1.0″>
     <dict>
 ⁣ ⁣     <key>AutoSelectCertificateForUrls</key>
 ⁣ ⁣ ⁣     <array>
 ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣     <string>{"pattern":"your_url","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"certificate name"}}}</string>
 ⁣ ⁣     ⁣</array>
    </dict>
    </plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows:

For those who have admin rights on a PC, there is a working solution for auto-selecting a certificate:

- for MAC enter  in terminal
  defaults write com.google.Chrome AutoSelectCertificateForUrls -array-add -string '"pattern":"your_url","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"certificate name"}}}'
- ⁣In Windows, you need to add the following example to the registry
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls\1 =
  ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣ ⁣"{"pattern":"your_url","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"certificate name"}}}"*/